# Javascript JSON Data to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, json, xml, html-table

I have some code which I'll paste below now. What the code does is read the contents of an XML file and put it into a JSON. Then puts the data from the JSON into a HTML table. All works fine except one thing. When the table is created the first row (after the column headings) always shows up as "undefined" in each cell. I've had a look through this code and cannot find anything that would cause it but I'm not an expert and I'm sure a fresh pair of eyes would help so any ideas?

```
<html>
<head>
<h1><u>USA State Information</u></h1>
</head>
<body>
<p><b>Please select an area of the USA in the dropdown list below.</b></p>
<p><select name="area" onchange="findXML(this.value)">

<?php
//set directory and open it
$xmldir = 'XML';
$dir = opendir($xmldir);

//create array and read through files in directory
$xmlfiles = array();
while ($file = readdir($dir))
{
    //if the first char is not '.' then add to array
    if (substr($file,-1,1) !== ".")
    {
        $xmlfiles[] = $file;
    }
    else
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}

echo '<option value="select">Select</option>';

foreach($xmlfiles as $area){ 
    echo '<option value="'.$area.'">'.$area.'</option>'; 
}
echo '</select>';

//close directory
closedir($dir);
?>
</p>
<p>
<div id=tbl>
</div>
<table id="elems" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td><b>Name</></td>
<td><b>Number</></td>
<td><b>Joined</></td>
<td><b>Population</></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
function findXML($area) {
$area = "XML/" + $area;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",$area,true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
//find number of elements in the XML file
$length = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name").length;

var JSONObject = [{}];
for (i=0; i!=$length; i++){
    //do something

    JSONObject.push(
    { "name":(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue),
    "number":(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("number")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue), 
    "joined":(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("joined")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue),
    "population":(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("population")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue) }
    );
}

r=1;
i=0;
for (i=0; i!=($length); i++){

    var tblr = document.getElementById("elems").insertRow(r);
    var cell1= tblr.insertCell(0);
    var cell2= tblr.insertCell(1);
    var cell3= tblr.insertCell(2);
    var cell4= tblr.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = JSONObject[i].name;
    cell2.innerHTML = JSONObject[i].number;
    cell3.innerHTML = JSONObject[i].joined;
    cell4.innerHTML = JSONObject[i].population;
    r++;
}

}
</script>
</p>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a stylistic concern. Why not `tblr.insertCell(0).innerHTML = JSONObject[i].name;`? There is no need for these variables. Also, your `var` statements inside of the `for` loop are logically wrong: they are variables that are either local to the containing function or global to the window! You *cannot* declare variables inside of a `for` loop. To understand more about the javascript code quality, you might start using a tool like [jshint.com](http://jshint.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue:

```
var JSONObject = [{}];
```

should be

```
var JSONObject = [];
```

The reason this fixes the issue is that you're iterating through the `JSONObject` array starting at the first index. This is fine, but the way you initialized the array gives the first index an empty object. When you go to get the properties `name`, `number`, etc., the empty object won't have them and they'll be returned as undefined.

Comment: Thank you SO much! Just tried this and it has solved the problem! Can't believe I didn't notice this before, haha! Thanks again!

Comment: @Kimmy25 If this solved your answer please click the check mark to the left of the post underneath the up/down arrows.

Comment: I've tried. I've got to wait a few more minutes but will do so when it's available :)

Comment: @Kimmy25 Ah, my apologies! :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

for (i=**1**; i!=($length); i++){

It may be your index starts from 1 and not 0

Comment: This will actually fix the issue but it's not the "correct" solution. Arrays are always 0 indexed.